# Retrieving data from csv are 0 or null

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-core, .net-core, csvhelper

I' trying to import from a CSV some data into c#. The problem that i'm facing is that the data are 0 or null. although I map their headers with the CSV headers.

This are some photos of what the csv file has and what I get when I debug with the following code. What i'm doing wrong?

This is the model of the CSV

```
 public class CsvModel
{
    [Name("EAN")]
    public string EAN { get; set; }
    [Name("Store Id")]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    [Name("Quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [Name("Amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    [Name("Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

and this is how I retrieve it

```
         public ActionResult Index( IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<CsvModel> m = new List<CsvModel>();

            if (uploadedFile != null && uploadedFile.Length > 0)
            {

                if (uploadedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".csv"))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(uploadedFile.OpenReadStream()))
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                    {

                        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvHeaderMap>();
                        var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvModel>();
                        foreach (var r in records)
                        {
                            CsvModel o = new CsvModel();
                            o.Date = r.Date;
                            o.Amount = r.Amount;
                            m.Add(r);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And this is how I map the headers

```
  public class CsvHeaderMap : ClassMap<CsvModel>
{
    public CsvHeaderMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("EAN");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Store Id");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Quantity");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Amount");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Date");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manual class mapping is overriding the attributes

```
public class CsvHeaderMap : ClassMap<CsvModel>
{
    public CsvHeaderMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("EAN");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Store Id");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Quantity");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Amount");
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("Date");
    }
}
```

Notice how in your image only the last map actually populates.

Either fix the mapping to map to the proper property

```
public class CsvHeaderMap : ClassMap<CsvModel> {
    public CsvHeaderMap() {
        Map(m => m.EAN).Name("EAN");
        Map(m => m.StoreId ).Name("Store Id");
        Map(m => m.Quantity).Name("Quantity");
        Map(m => m.Amount).Name("Amount");
        Map(m => m.Date).Name("Date");
    }
}
```

or remove it completely and let the system figure it out automagically from the attributes.